How can I install multiple Odoo modules at once using a single custom module?
I’m working on an Odoo project where I frequently need to install both the contacts and hr modules. Is there a way to create a "wrapper" module that, when installed, automatically installs these two modules as dependencies?

Yes, you can achieve this by creating a dummy module that has contacts and hr as dependencies. Here's how to do it:
Create a new module, let's call it Wrapper.
In the _ _ manifest _ _.py file of Wrapper, set contacts and hr as dependencies like this:
{
    'name': 'Module Wrapper',
    'version': '1.0',
    'summary': 'Wrapper module that installs Contacts and HR',
    'depends': ['contacts', 'hr'],  # Specify dependencies here
    'data': [],
    'installable': True,
    'auto_install': False,
}

This module doesn’t need to contain any functionality or models itself. When you install Wrapper, Odoo will automatically install the contacts and hr modules because they are listed in the depends field.
Why is this useful?
Time Saver: Instead of manually installing both contacts and hr each time, you can just install Wrapper.
Testing Convenience: If you have test cases or workflows involving contacts and hr, testing module Wrapper ensures that both modules and their respective test cases are also loaded.
